# Android emulator launch error from jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, emulation

I am facing the **error below only when am running using batch command from Jenkins** but works fine when i run through a .bat file in my local folder. Please help with this. [My image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gZdS.png)

> emulator: ERROR: Unknown AVD name [Pixel2], use -list-avds to see valid list.
>   HOME is defined but there is no file Pixel2.ini in $HOME.android\avd
>   (Note: Directories are searched in the order $ANDROID_AVD_HOME, $ANDROID_SDK_HOME\avd and $HOME.android\avd)

Note: I have tried all the suggestions mentioned from Search results so far such as setting new environment variable such as ANDROID_SDK_HOME etc. but none helped.